# Existe operador comparador "in" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, característica-linguagem, operadores

Em JavaScript existe uma forma de usar `in` para verificar se o valor de uma variável está contido em uma lista de valores?

Um exemplo visual:

```
if (tipoDemissao in [1, 2, 5]){
    valorDemissao = 525.20;
}
```

Comment: Existe, mas é para checar propriedades em um objeto: [**in - MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: Baseado no seu código acho que você pode fazer com indexOf de uma olhada nesse [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/8nLg7n6o/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Na versão ECMAScript 2016 (ES7) podes usar [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) que é o que procuras para listas/*arrays*.

Nesse caso o método retorna um booleano:

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2); // true
[1, 2, 3].includes(9); // false
```

**Em objetos**, como referiste há o `in`, para verificar propriedades de objetos.

```
'foo' in {foo: 'bar'} // true
'so' in {foo: 'bar'} // false
```

Ou podes usar também `.hasOwnProperty('foo')`, que mostra só as propriedades da instância.

Em *strings* e também *arrays* há o `indexOf()` como o [@Maniero indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122838/129). Aí o método retorna a posição do que foi procurado na `Array` ou `String`. Se o resultado for `>= 0` então é porque existe.

Comment: @durtto só é bom esclarecer que uso isto só funcionará em navegadores que suportam este recurso, os outros falharão.

Answer (score 7):

Não existe. Precisa usar algum truque, criar uma função ou usar uma biblioteca. Exemplo:

```
if ([1, 2, 5].indexOf(tipoDemissao) > -1) valorDemissao = 525.20;
```

Se puder usar [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) tem:

```
if ($.inArray(tipoDemissao, [1, 2, 5])) valorDemissao = 525.20;
```

Agora que só se usa *browsers* modernos já pode ser interessante usar uma função nova que dá o que espera:

```
if ([1, 2, 5].includes(tipoDemissao)) valorDemissao = 525.20;
```

Se isto não resolver totalmente o que deseja, a solução é criar uma função `contains()` que trate tudo do jeito que precisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/In.js).

Comment: `contains` só dá para fazer em texto, `"olá mundo".contains('mundo')` => `true`

Comment: Por isso que eu disse que teria que criar uma.

Comment: O que quis dizer foi: Criar uma função `contains` pode dar aso a confusão, uma vez que ja existe `string.contains` - tirando isso, top notch de resposta :)

Answer (score 5):

Dependendo do cenário pode ser interessante fazer isso, por proporcionar mais possibilidades:

```
var listaDeNumeros = [2,4,6,8,10];
var numeroAhProcurar = 6;

for(numero in listaDeNumeros){
    if (numeroAhProcurar == listaDeNumeros[numero]){
        alert("Numero " + listaDeNumeros[numero] + " encontrado");
    }
}
```